# A method to send multiple "key":"value" pairs in JSON

Tags: c#, javascript, json, websocket, json.net

I have a javascript file which communicates with a c# application through a websocket. The JS file contains many fucntions with different parameters. I use JSON to send a request and receive a response and its format is given below.

```
{
    "request": "connect",
    "parameters":
     { 
     "key": "value",
     },
    "pid": "23avavAASD3fafdsAFE",
}
```

The response has the same format. Now for the "key": "value" pairs I want to have different values according to the function being called like shown below.

```
{
        "request": "connect",
        "parameters":
         { 
         "GIT_COMMIT": "23avavAASD3fafdsAFE",
         ".NET_VERSION":"4.0",
         },
        "pid": "23avavAASD3fafdsAFE",
}
```

Now I cant figure out how to send and receive these parameters in C# using JSON.NET because the parameters are different with each request and response.

What is the best way to send this kind of JSON string?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can't you just receive them as a dictionary of string,string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model these key/value pairs as a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and serialize it with [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

```
public class Request
{
    public string request { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string,string> parameters { get; set; }
    public string pid { get; set; }
}


var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(data);
```

Comment: Please help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716358/how-to-iterate-data-to-insert-into-a-list-to-create-a-json-format-data

Answer (score 0):

Just create a type that matches the JSON you use to send data, and for storing the parameters, you would use a key/value pair collection.